Pure-ftpd set up for TLS "AUth command unsupported"
I enabled TLS on pure-ftpd as per instructions. Created DH file, installed certificates, increased the logging level.
Now, when connecting from filezilla, I receive a hello stating that TLS is enabled/supported, but then it says that "AUTH TLS" command is not supported.
Here's the client log:
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 11:10. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   502-Auth command is not supported.
Response:   502-Please contact your network administrator to enable FTPS service.

Does anyone have an idea why it isn't working? On server, I only have "new connection" and "logout":
Jul 19 11:09:17 ServerName pure-ftpd-mysql[1570744]: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-mysql -l mysql:/etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf -l pam -J HIGH -p 29799:29899 -A -j -E -u 33 -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -Y 2 -d -B
Jul 19 11:09:17 ServerName systemd[1]: Started pure-ftpd-mysql.service.

Jul 19 11:09:58 ServerName pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.xx.xx.xxx) [INFO] New connection from xxx.xx.xx.xxx
Jul 19 11:10:18 ServerName pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.xx.xx.xxx) [INFO] Logout.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make it work?
BTW when connecting from terminal (cleartext, Y=2), pure-ftp states only TLS is available, so apparently it should work:
may@XXX:~$ ftp ftp.xxx.yy
Connected to xxx.yy.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:24. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (ftp.xxx.xx:zzz): xxxxxxxx
421-Sorry, cleartext sessions and weak ciphers are not accepted on this server.
421 Please reconnect using TLS security mechanisms.
ftp: Login failed
ftp> 

Thanks.

It sounds like you're trying explicit TLS which involves making a non-TLS connection on port 21 and then uses the "AUTH TLS" FTP command to upgrade the connection to TLS.  You might want to try implicit TLS which involves making a TLS connection to port 990 (TCP handshake followed immediately by TLS Client Hello). Maybe your pure-ftpd setup is only set up for the more common implicit TLS.
